# Split a string at a natural break

Tags: python

While rendering a title (using reportlab), I would like to split it between two lines if it is longer than 45 characters.  So far I have this:

```
if len(Title) < 45:
    drawString(200, 695, Title)
else:
    drawString(200, 705, Title[:45])
    drawString(200, 685, Title[45:])
```

The problem with this is that I only want to split the title at a natural break, such as where a space occurs.  How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: what if there's no natural break e.g., blank, past 44 characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this sample code :

```
import textwrap

print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap("This is my sooo long title", 10)))
```

The output :

```
This is my
sooo long
title
```

See full Python doc : http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap

Comment: The stuff built into Python continues to surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rfind(' ', 0, 45)` to find the last space before the boundary and break at that position. If there's no space (rfind returns -1), use the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'this is a long line with a bunch of text for sure and goes on and on ..'

brk = s.find(' ', 45)
if brk == -1:
    print s
else:
    print('{:s}\n{:s}'.format(s[:brk], s[brk+1:]))
```

Roll your own and perhaps not that elegant .. yields:

```
this is a long line with a bunch of text for sure
and goes on and on ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about alternatives. I could suggest, draw the text box with back ground color as background page with width= 45 and ShrinkToFit=1. So text more than 45 will be shrinked at end of words..