# Text-To-Speech causing ANRs with most drivers and long texts

Tags: android, text-to-speech, sigabrt, android-anr-dialog

My app allows to send and queue paragraphs to the TTS engine. Think of a book, you long-press a paragraph, and it is sent to the TTS engine in QUEUE mode.

This always worked flawlessly in Androids pre-Jelly bean, however in KitKats, Jelly Beans and Amazon Kindle HDX (custom Jelly-Bean),queueing 3 or 4 medium-to-long texts (15 lines) cause the App to stop responding, and even the kernel issuing a SIGABRT to kill it.

It happens with `Google Voice` engine and `Pico TTS` engine. `IVONA TTS` (a third party commercial engine) does not have this problem, you can queue hundreds of texts without problem.

Anybody facing this problem? Below is a typical stacktrace for a crashing TTS engine, this one is for pico TTS (com.svox.pico)

```
I/InputDispatcher(  837): Application is not responding: Window{421687a0 u0 tv.nebular.funq/tv.nebular.funq.story.StoryDesign}.  It has been 5003.9ms since event, 5002.2ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
I/WindowManager(  837): Input event dispatching timed out sending to tv.nebular.funq/tv.nebular.funq.story.StoryDesign
I/Process (  837): Sending signal. PID: 30401 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(30401): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(30401): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
E/ActivityManager(  837): ANR in tv.nebular.funq (tv.nebular.funq/.story.StoryDesign)
E/ActivityManager(  837): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
E/ActivityManager(  837): Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
E/ActivityManager(  837): CPU usage from 42481ms to 0ms ago:
E/ActivityManager(  837):   10% 29001/com.svox.pico: 10% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 852 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   7.2% 30897/com.amazon.cloud9: 3.8% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 15 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   4.8% 429/mediaserver: 2.6% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 2 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   4.6% 427/surfaceflinger: 1.4% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 9 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   3.7% 30401/tv.nebular.funq: 3% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 2279 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   3.1% 476/sensors.qcom: 0.9% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 4 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   2.5% 7692/com.amazon.cloud9:sandboxed_process4: 1.1% user + 1.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   1.4% 1801/mpdecision: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.9% 837/system_server: 0.6% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 337 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.9% 31618/kworker/u:24: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.6% 484/mm-pp-daemon: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.5% 31602/kworker/u:4: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.5% 31604/kworker/u:6: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.5% 31605/kworker/u:7: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.4% 122/irq/333-synapti: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.4% 22402/kworker/0:0H: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.3% 938/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.3% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.2% 17566/kworker/0:3: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0.1% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 507/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 247/thermal-engine: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 30805/com.amazon.avod: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 45 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 151/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 2818/com.amazon.whisperlink.core.android: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 8811/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 23138/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 29086/com.audible.application.kindle: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 44/khubd: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 128/dbs_sync/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 129/dbs_sync/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 425/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 1085/com.amazon.client.metrics: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 1125/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 1156/com.amazon.device.logmanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 1176/com.amazon.tcomm: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 119 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 6146/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 19031/com.amazon.device.settings:Settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 27628/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 28020/com.amazon.whisperplay.cds:cds_services: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 28408/com.google.process.location: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 27 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 28491/com.amazon.venezia: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 29194/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 30454/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  837):   0% 31178/com.amazon.kindle: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
E/ActivityManager(  837): 41% TOTAL: 23% user + 17% kernel + 0.9% iowait + 0% irq + 0.1% softirq
E/ActivityManager(  837): CPU usage from 57345823ms to 57345823ms ago with 0% awake:
E/ActivityManager(  837): 0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
I/Process (  837): Sending signal. PID: 30401 SIG: 6
F/libc    (30401): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000345 (code=0), thread 30401 (tv.nebular.funq)
I/DEBUG   (  426): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  426): Build fingerprint: 'Amazon/thor/thor:4.2.2/JDQ39/13.3.2.5_user_325001120:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  426): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  426): pid: 30401, tid: 30401, name: tv.nebular.funq  >>> tv.nebular.funq <<<
I/DEBUG   (  426): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (  426):     r0 00000009  r1 c0186201  r2 be88c2a8  r3 be88c2a4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     r4 5cc0dcb0  r5 5cc0dc80  r6 5cc0dce0  r7 00000036
I/DEBUG   (  426):     r8 00000001  r9 00007206  sl 00007211  fp 40170228
I/DEBUG   (  426):     ip 40253f24  sp be88c288  lr 4014fa91  pc 4013c0ac  cpsr 88000010
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d0  0000000000000011  d1  000000100000000a
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000074
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d4  bde38e383dba2e6e  d5  be4ccccd3e124925
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d6  2708e8663eaaaaab  d7  43de5556c35e5554
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d8  453b8000453b9000  d9  3f8000003f800aec
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d10 400921fb44960000  d11 3fcfb597d6958340
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d12 4000000000000000  d13 3f0000003f3f6b30
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d14 000000003f3f6b30  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d16 00720064006e0061  d17 002e00640069006f
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d18 0065006500700073  d19 0074002e00680063
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d20 0049002e00730074  d21 0074007800650054
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d22 00700053006f0054  d23 0068006300650065
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 3fe5555555555555
I/DEBUG   (  426):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     scr 6800009f
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #00  pc 000170ac  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #01  pc 0002aa8d  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #02  pc 00016ba1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #03  pc 0001709d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+44)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #04  pc 000172b7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+114)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #05  pc 00014a3b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+34)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #06  pc 0006f3d3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #07  pc 00020ad0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #08  pc 00050161  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #09  pc 00029f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #10  pc 0002e02c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #11  pc 00062d67  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #12  pc 0006a6a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #13  pc 00029f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #14  pc 0002e02c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #15  pc 00062a91  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #16  pc 0004c693  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #17  pc 0004f8d5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #18  pc 0005057f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #19  pc 0000208f  /system/bin/app_process
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #20  pc 000127bf  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #21  pc 00001bd4  /system/bin/app_process
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c248  be88c424  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c24c  4090fdef  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c250  4097044b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c254  2f00002d
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c258  4079f648  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c25c  2f10002d
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c260  414c3368  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c264  d1500025
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c268  414c3368  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c26c  4091de8f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+34)
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c270  d1500025
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c274  5cc0dcb0
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c278  00000008
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c27c  5cc0dce0
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c280  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c284  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #00  be88c288  5cc0dcb0
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c28c  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #01  be88c290  00000009
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c294  be88c2a4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c298  40247ba5  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+136)
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c29c  c0186201
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2a0  be88c2a8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2a4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     #02  be88c2a8  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2ac  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2b0  5cbf9a58
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2b4  00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2b8  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2bc  5cbe2840
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2c0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2c4  5cc0dc80
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2c8  619006b0
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2cc  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2d0  00007205
I/DEBUG   (  426):          be88c2d4  402480a1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+48)
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c288 5cc0dcb0 00000001 00000009 be88c2a4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c298 40247ba5 c0186201 be88c2a8 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2a8 00000000 00000000 5cbf9a58 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2b8 00000000 5cbe2840 00000000 5cc0dc80
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2c8 619006b0 00000000 00007205 402480a1
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2d8 5cbf9a64 00000000 60a3cc78 4024aee1
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2e8 5cc0dce0 5cc0dcb0 40286300 40247cff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2f8 40992be8 00000011 00000000 0000000a
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c308 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000074
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c318 00000000 44e35090 00000000 5cc0dc80
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c328 619006b0 00000010 00000011 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c338 0000000a 60a3cc78 d1500025 402482bb
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c348 0000000a 60a3cc78 00000000 e5a44070
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c358 0000f424 40160720 00000000 5dbe1e68
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c368 414c2e08 00000000 0000000a 000f4240
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c378 00000000 88c40700 00003426 619006b0
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c284 00000000 5cc0dcb0 00000001 00000009
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c294 be88c2a4 40247ba5 c0186201 be88c2a8
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 5cbf9a58
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2b4 00000100 00000000 5cbe2840 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2c4 5cc0dc80 619006b0 00000000 00007205
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2d4 402480a1 5cbf9a64 00000000 60a3cc78
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2e4 4024aee1 5cc0dce0 5cc0dcb0 40286300
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2f4 40247cff 40992be8 00000011 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c304 0000000a 00000010 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c314 00000074 00000000 44e35090 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c324 5cc0dc80 619006b0 00000010 00000011
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c334 00000000 0000000a 60a3cc78 d1500025
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c344 402482bb 0000000a 60a3cc78 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c354 e5a44070 0000f424 40160720 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c364 5dbe1e68 414c2e08 00000000 0000000a
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c374 000f4240 00000000 88c40700 00003426
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dc90 00000000 00000007 00000004 40251670
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dca0 00000000 00000000 00000007 00000004
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcb0 00000000 5cbe2840 00000008 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcc0 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcd0 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dce0 00000000 5cbf9a58 00000000 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcf0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd00 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd10 00000000 000076c1 00002710 00000304
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd20 00000000 00000023 00730041 00610069
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd30 0041002f 00740071 00750061 5b550000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd40 59e7f650 00000023 59e81cba 4016fcc4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd50 00000000 00000000 25700000 426429f0
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd60 6f666e49 00000023 407abd28 00000003
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd70 00000008 5cc0dd88 40890f2d 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd80 00000000 00000033 5cc0dd48 5cc0e2f0
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dc60 0063006f 00730075 00640065 006c005f
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dc70 00670069 00740068 f4df0000 000000ab
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dc80 5b557bd8 000076c1 40251628 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dc90 00000000 00000007 00000004 40251670
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dca0 00000000 00000000 00000007 00000004
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcb0 00000000 5cbe2840 00000008 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcc0 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcd0 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dce0 00000000 5cbf9a58 00000000 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcf0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd00 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd10 00000000 000076c1 00002710 00000304
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd20 00000000 00000023 00730041 00610069
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd30 0041002f 00740071 00750061 5b550000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd40 59e7f650 00000023 59e81cba 4016fcc4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd50 00000000 00000000 25700000 426429f0
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcc0 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcd0 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dce0 00000000 5cbf9a58 00000000 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dcf0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd00 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd10 00000000 000076c1 00002710 00000304
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd20 00000000 00000023 00730041 00610069
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd30 0041002f 00740071 00750061 5b550000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd40 59e7f650 00000023 59e81cba 4016fcc4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd50 00000000 00000000 25700000 426429f0
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd60 6f666e49 00000023 407abd28 00000003
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd70 00000008 5cc0dd88 40890f2d 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd80 00000000 00000033 5cc0dd48 5cc0e2f0
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dd90 5cc0e310 00000000 00000000 800021a8
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0dda0 00000000 012c9b17 012bb38b 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  426):     5cc0ddb0 00000030 0000003b 00000001 00000020
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000071e4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000071f4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007204 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007214 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007224 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007234 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007244 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007254 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007264 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007274 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007284 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007294 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000071f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007200 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007210 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007220 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007230 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007240 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007250 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007260 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007270 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007280 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     00007290 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     000072e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170208 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170218 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170228 44e35090 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170258 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40170298 00000000 00000000 0080d1db 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     401702f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f04 40201f69 4013d700 40133948 4013bf24
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f14 4013ba44 40202e61 4013389c 4013369c
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f24 4014fa7d 40137811 40204219 40140f89
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f34 4013bc7c 40180a31 401438b5 40201723
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f44 402017bf 40141a9d 40202799 4015f090
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f54 4013bfd4 40143dad 40201957 402016b5
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f64 4013c578 401410e9 40183979 401839f5
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f74 4013e8e0 4014a157 4017f6d7 4017f707
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f84 4017f6ef 40202b49 40202bb5 40202bd9
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253f94 402029ed 40202b99 40131fa9 40131f95
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253fa4 40131fd1 4019d8e9 4019d8f7 40201f13
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253fb4 40201701 4020332d 4020310b 401410c3
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253fc4 4013ff9d 402041c5 402010a9 40200f31
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253fd4 4014a451 401805e1 4017f170 40202eed
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253fe4 40203155 40202c09 401feead 402030b1
I/DEBUG   (  426):     40253ff4 402030f9 402030a5 402030ed 40254000
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c268 414c3368 4091de8f d1500025 5cc0dcb0
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c278 00000008 5cc0dce0 df0027ad 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c288 5cc0dcb0 00000001 00000009 be88c2a4
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c298 40247ba5 c0186201 be88c2a8 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2a8 00000000 00000000 5cbf9a58 00000100
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2b8 00000000 5cbe2840 00000000 5cc0dc80
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2c8 619006b0 00000000 00007205 402480a1
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2d8 5cbf9a64 00000000 60a3cc78 4024aee1
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2e8 5cc0dce0 5cc0dcb0 40286300 40247cff
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c2f8 40992be8 00000011 00000000 0000000a
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c308 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000074
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c318 00000000 44e35090 00000000 5cc0dc80
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c328 619006b0 00000010 00000011 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c338 0000000a 60a3cc78 d1500025 402482bb
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c348 0000000a 60a3cc78 00000000 e5a44070
I/DEBUG   (  426):     be88c358 0000f424 40160720 00000000 5dbe1e68
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c08c e3a070db ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c09c 512fff1e ea0093ad e92d0090 e3a07036
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0ac ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0bc ea0093a6 e92d0090 e3a07091 ef000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0cc e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e ea00939f
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0dc e92d0090 e3a07092 ef000000 e8bd0090
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0ec e1b00000 512fff1e ea009398 e92d0090
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c0fc e3a07037 ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c10c 512fff1e ea009391 e92d0090 e3a0708f
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c11c ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c12c ea00938a e92d0090 e3a0705e ef000000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c13c e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e ea009383
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c14c e92d0090 e3a07029 ef000000 e8bd0090
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c15c e1b00000 512fff1e ea00937c e92d0090
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c16c e3a0702a ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4013c17c 512fff1e ea009375 e92d0090 e59f7010
I/DEBUG   (  426):
I/DEBUG   (  426): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fa70 b00afecf bf00bd70 0001d52c b503b40e
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fa80 f852aa03 1d131b04 93019a04 eb0af7ec
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fa90 400ce8bd 4770b003 530af3c1 0b30ec41
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014faa0 f021b97b 43014100 eddfd065 ee601b35
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fab0 4b3b0ba1 ec51429a da0a0b30 1b32eddf
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fac0 f240e057 428370ff ee70bf08 d1030ba0
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fad0 f3c1e051 3b36530a f2401898 429873fe
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fae0 ec51dd02 e0150b30 dd0a2800 41fef021
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014faf0 2b30ec53 0170f421 5300ea41 2b30ec43
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb00 f110e039 da270f35 3350f24c ec51429a
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb10 dd0f0b30 4100f001 e9d3a31d f0412300
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb20 eddf43fc f4430b1b f443135e f04343c8
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb30 e00e033c 4100f001 e9d3a313 f0412300
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb40 eddf73d2 f4430b11 f44333b6 f0437307
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb50 ec430303 e00c2b31 f0213036 f42141fe
I/DEBUG   (  426):     4014fb60 ec530170 ea412b30 eddf5300 ec430b0b
```

Comment: Are you limiting to `getMaxSpeechInputLength()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getMaxSpeechInputLength()

Comment: no I'm not.. should I?

Comment: Your error log doesn't reveal much to me, so it's certainly the place I'd start. There will be a limit to how much each engine can handle, but the above parameter can't be changed by the default engine, which is a bit rubbish. Stick within the limit and see if that solves it for a start - There's some sample code on splitting utterances in my question here --> http://stackoverflow.com/q/23353671/1256219

Comment: gonna try, thanks for pointing me towards this interesting parameter. However it's funny that an old tablet with ICS and same engine is able to swallow hundreds of texts without problem

Comment: It's not the definite solution - but if you're firing in thousands of words, it will eventually ANR. Devices and OS versions have their quirks; I wish they didn't! Let me know if you want me to put some sample code in an answer

Comment: i will probably have to rewrite my logic so instead of using QUEUE mode I'll listen for an utterance completion event then queue it myself manually... Your linked question to split in a natural position is interesting for such a thing. I think I'll be very conservative and just send small sentences, because each engine ANR's differently, for example Google Voice is the first to crash, Pico TTS is somewhat better, and Ivona TTS is the best (apparently never crashes), but it's a shame it's commercial so its use is not very widespread.

Comment: I think that's the safest idea. I've written a TTS engine and some work is done on the UI thread. Adding utterances when another is complete (or there is only one other pending) sounds like a plan. Good luck!

Comment: I have implemented manual queueing using a PriorityQueue, and the function to add stuff (text) is also passed through your splitting routine, so I can arbitrarily add long paragraphs that insert dozens of small utterances into the queue. Then as end-of-utterance events arrive, I fetch the next sentence from the queue until it's empty. Everything works like a charm now :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Let me know if you want me to put it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of your question, there is a parameter [getMaxSpeechInputLength()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getMaxSpeechInputLength()) which returns the maximum length of characters an can engine support.

However, the current default engine can not alter this parameter, which makes it redundant to check and through experimentation, many can support much larger input.

The [Google Eyes Free project adheres to this parameter](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/accessibilityServices/talkback/src/com/google/android/marvin/talkback/FeedbackProcessingUtils.java?spec=svn821&r=821#103) - and at some point, everything will grind to a halt if you feed an entire book in to process! That will no doubt explain your ANR

If you'd like to handle splitting the text at more natural language breaks (rather than just spaces), there is [some sample code in my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353671/1256219). As the question states, it'll win no awards for presentation, but it's fast and does the job.

Comment: it sure does.. I modified it a little and it's perfect for my needs.